# How do I implement the param startYear and endYear?

Tags: python

I have a hard time understanding of how to implement the startYear and the endYear params. I open the file name then it reads the data. Then it will read the user's inputs for state, gender, startYear, and endYear. As what I have it looks at the gender and if it matches the input then it goes on the startYear and if it matches then it will append to the list.

```
Get the top names.
:param state (str): The state, e.g. 'NY'
:param gender (str): The gender, e.g. 'F'
:param startYear (int): The starting year, e.g. 1969
:param endYear (int): The ending year, e.g. 2010
:return: The list of top Name objects
:rtype: list

def getTopNames(state, gender, startYear, endYear):

    fileName = 'data/' + state + '.TXT'

    topName = []

    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f:
            loon = line.split()
            if loon[1] == gender:
                 if line[2] == startYear:
                    Name += line[3]

            topName.append(createName(loon[0], loon[1], int(loon[2]), int(loon[3])))
    return topName
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your question and format your post properly.

Answer (score 0):

If `startYear` is an integer (as suggested by your parameter list), then you need to convert it to a string before you can meaningfully compare it with one:

```
>>> startYear = 1999
>>> startYear == "1999"
False
>>> startYear = str(startYear)
>>> startYear == "1999"
True
```

Furthermore, I suspect that you meant

```
if loon[2] == startYear: # instead of line[2] which would be a single character
```

Lastly, no need to nest the `if`s:

```
if loon[1] == gender and loon[2] == startYear:
    Name += loon[3]
```